# Stove Burner Gets too hot? But not switch

Tags: stove

I bought my house a year ago and over that time we noticed the dual burner on the stove top (front burner, right side) seems to always get too hot even when the switch is set on low. We often end up burning dishes.

I chalked it up to being a crummy brand and tended to avoid using that burner. But after doing some research it seemed the solution was to replace the dual infinity switch. I replaced the switch and the burner works but it still seems like the same problem continues to happen. I didn't want to believe it at first but it was as if nothing changed at all. Everything I've found online says the solution is to replace the switch. I suppose I could replace the element but based on what I've read that won't fix this particular problem.

Model Number: FEF368GCE  - Brand: Frigidaire

Comment: What model stove is this?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel FEF368GCE

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat similar models have been recalled in the past, however your model **IS NOT** listed (yours is Model Number: FEF368GCE, [I'm assuming](http://forum.appliancepartspros.com/oven-repair-including-ranges-cooktops/566284-frigidaire-stove-burner-gets-too-hot-replaced-infinity-switch.html)).

> Hazard:  Depending on the model, the surface heating elements can 1) turn on spontaneously without being switched on; 2) fail to turn off after being switched off; or, **3) heat to different temperatures than selected.** This poses a fire and burn hazard to consumers. –[smoothtoprangerecall.com](http://www.smoothtoprangerecall.com/node42.aspx)

I have never worked on, or even used an electric stove. **I suggest contacting the manufacturer**. I might leave out the part about not using OEM parts, then again that could be the problem... if it's the wrong resistance or something, that could certainly be it.

(perhaps the element is fused or broken, but that's just guess work)

Answer (score 2):

On an older stove, it's the control knob switch.
On a digital stove, the problem is a stuck contact inside the one of the 4 relays, (little black cubes) on the circuit board, that feeds the affected element.
When stuck, it by-passes all the controls and sends the current direct to the element.
I cracked mine open and filed the contacts, but ordered a couple spare relays at a cost of about 2$.
Companies will insist the complete board be changed, for no less than 200$.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.